# jQuery Accordion, when expanded shows visual artifact in Google Chrome extension's popup window, only on a Mac

Tags: css, macos, jquery-ui, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Google Chrome extension. Its popup window has the [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) control inside. The popup page is laid out using html/css similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topLogo">
    <!-- static or unmovable content on top -->
</div>

<div id="mainSection">
    <div id="accordion">
        <!-- Accordion stuff here -->
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
html,body{

    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    min-width: 24em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.topLogo{
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0px 0px 58px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#mainSection{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 400px;  /* The height is actually defined in JS before page is displayed */
    border-top: thin solid #EEE;
}
```

The way it works can be illustrated on this diagram:

[image]

The top part of the popup window is a static or non-movable section, while the Accordion is a scrollable DIV. It's height is dictated by the number of tabs in the Accordion itself. The bottom DIV begins scrolling only if its overall height exceeds Chrome's predefined 600 pixels or so.

The Accordion itself originally has all of its tabs closed and only when a user clicks on one of its tabs, it expands down. This in turn expands the popup window itself, as such:

[image]

Note that I didn't write any special code for any of the functionality above. It is all done from within the `jQuery UI` library.

OK so, this all works fine on a Windows version of Google Chrome, but when I run the same exact extension on the latest version of Chrome on my Mac OS X, when I click on any Accordion tab to expand it, the popup window begins making this weird "shaky"/jittery motion while expanding, and it is very visible. So I'm curious, what shall I do to prevent that awful looking artifact on a Mac?

**UPDATE**: I was able to build a test extension that demonstrates the issue. It is just a plain popup window with the included jQuery library. (Here's the link to it: [TestExtPopupOSX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7N3W2etVDfQXhJZUVLT2tUcEk/view?usp=sharing)) Can someone please try it?

Here's a GIF that I recorded with it. Unfortunately due to low fps rate it doesn't really show it well, but you can kinda see the jerky-ness:

[image]

Comment: I think the effect is due to gradual resizing of the the popup window itself. It could be potentially fixed by instantly setting the size to the expected full size on click, so that the window expands and then the animation plays to fill the height. Try it.

Comment: @Xan: Thanks, I thought about it too. But how do you set the size of the popup window before it's displayed?

Comment: @Xan: Listen, I appreciate you taking time on this. I was able to build a small sample extension to illustrate the issue (it's in my updated question above.) Is there any way you can take a look?

Comment: Sorry, can't spare time in the next few days to take a deeper look. I would say by the way that it's a proper bug; search through issues on https://crbug.com/ and then report it. You even have a screengrab and a minimal example for it.

Comment: @Xan: I understand. I'll try to get more info on it but at this point I don't even know where to start -- jQuery or Chrome itself. So I'll keep digging and if you find a spare moment I'd appreciate your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: In fact there is also a 'shaky' effect on Windows, maybe only under specific releases of Chrome, mine is 56.0.2924.87